# Develop new theme without affecting the active one

Tags: theme-development

Hi I will really appreciate your input.
I just got a new template for wp. I want to start working on it without affecting the template already installed and running on the server.

what's the best way to work around it? someone told me to create a new directory and install wp in that directory, which i did but it shows a 404 page

Sincerely

Jim

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you should install WAMP or MAMP and develop locally. Then only you can see the site in progress and you don't have to wait for files to upload to view changes. You're just saving locally.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the [Theme Switcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nkthemeswitch/) plugin. Enable only for the administrator.

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way:**
Just put the following as wrapper around your code to avoid people seeing what you do:

```
// Add Template comment here and assign your test template to a 'private' page.
/*
Template Name: TESTTEMPLATE
*/

// Here we start with the template part that only admins can see:
if ( current_use_can( 'administrator' ) 
{

// DO STUFF HERE

// after the following line everything is public again.
}
else
{

// ADDITIONAL: redirect to home
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

wp_redirect( home_url() );
// could also be the last page
// $redirectURL = trim ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// wp_redirect( $redirectULR );

exit;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm agree with curtismchale..
but if you are new to wordpress than

i suggest you to first install latest XAMPP via installer from here - [installer](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)

or WAMP from here - [installer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php) and work locally first..

install latest wordpress and extract it and put folder "wordpress" as directed below

1] for xampp you should put "wordpress" in "../xampp/htdocs"
2] for wamp you should put "wordpress" in "../wamp/www"

install wordpress(hope you know) put your tamplate in "wordpress/wp-content/themes" than go to admin and activate your theme from appearance->themes->your theme-> and activate it.
and start working on it..

hope this will help you...

Comment: Hi yj18 i did the install but now is asking me if i have :    * Are you sure you have the correct username and password? YES
    * Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname? YES
    * Are you sure that the database server is running? NOT SURE

Comment: @JIM - Heres the best article I've found on setting up your XAMPP server.  I refer to it regularly, even though I've done it several times on several machines. http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/web-development-tutorials/using-xampp-for-local-wordpress-theme-development/  It may take you 15 minutes to redo your install, but it would be time well spent.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin [Theme Test Drive](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-test-drive/) is what I use to preview themes on a live site (for those times you need too) without affecting what normal users see when they visit your site. You can make themes only visible to administrators, whilst everyone else gets the old default theme you have set.

Just what you were after. Some helpful advice is to develop locally, it makes things so much easier and then FTP'ing the files to your server once you are happy with what you have locally.

Download a copy of [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and it'll give you an easy and pre set up version of PHP, Apache and MySQL to work with on your own machine locally.